# How to use sed w command inside {}

Tags: bash, sed

This works fine:

```
printf "%s\n" data_{1..10} | sed -n '/_2$/ s/a/e/gw file'
```

But if I try something like this:

```
printf "%s\n" data_{1..10} | sed -n '/_2$/ { s/a/e/gw file }'
```

I get:

```
sed: -e expression #2, char 0: unmatched `{'
```

If I replace `w file` with `p` it works fine inside `{}`. This works:

```
printf "%s\n" data_{1..10} | sed -n '/_2$/ { s/a/e/gp }'
```

So, why `w` works without `{}` and why not inside `{}`? and how can I use  it inside `{}`?

Comment: Separate commands with a semicolon.

Comment: Also, terminate commands inside of `{ }` pairs with a semicolon, i.e. `sed '{...;} file`. AND `-e` isn't really needed in this case. `sed '/_2$/{s/a/e/gw file2 ;};/_5$/ {s/a/e/gw file5;}' file` should work too. Some seds may require further `;`s. i.e. `sed '/_2$/{;s/a/e/gw file2;};/_5$/ {;s/a/e/gw file5;}' file`Good luck.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks! I tried separating command with semicolon: `printf "%s\n" data_{1..10}|sed -n '/_2$/ { s/a/e/g;w file2 }'` and `printf "%s\n" data_{1..10}|sed -n '/_2$/ { s/a/e/g;w file2; }'`, and `printf "%s\n" data_{1..10}|sed -n '/_2$/ { s/a/e/gw file2; }'`, but got `sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched {'`. If I use `p` instead of `w` I have no problem even without semicolon: `printf "%s\n" data_{1..10}|sed '/_2$/ { s/a/e/gp }'`

Comment: @shellter Thanks! but I copy-paste both of your suggestions and got `sed: couldn't open file file2 ;};/_5$/ {s/a/e/gw file5;}: No such file or directory`. If I replace the `w fileX` with `p` I have no problem, with or without all the semicolons, this works fine: `sed -n '/_2$/{s/a/e/gp};/_5$/ {s/a/e/gp}' file`

Comment: @shellter I simplified the example as the `sed -e 'command1' -e 'command2'` is irrelevant for the illustration of the problem I have, my bad :(.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I dug in on this and found you'll need to have `gw file2` the last text on a line, and then continue on next line with closing `}`. Been a while since I actively used `s/a/b/gw file2` ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: see also https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Multiple-commands-syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything on the line after `w` is being parsed as a filename.  That is, sed is trying to write to a file named `file }`  (or, it would if the open `{` had a matching `}`, but it doesn't.)  Try adding a newline:

```
printf "%s\n" data_{1..10} | sed -n '/_2$/ { s/a/e/gw file
}'
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ne '/_2$/{s/a/e/gw fileOut' -e '}' fileIn
```

or using a bit of bash syntactic sugar:

```
sed -n $'/_2$/{s/a/e/gw fileOut\n}' fileIn
```

However since there is only one command following the address:

```
sed -n '/_2$/s/a/e/gw fileOut' fileIn
```

is the preferred way.

Or:

```
sed -e '/_2$/s/a/e/gw fileOut' -e 'd' fileIn
```

Comment: Great, thanks! By the way, there is only one command in the example as it is to illustrate the problem in the simplest way. I would not have this problem if there were just that one command since I would not need the {}, and as I said at the beginning of my question, it works fine without the {}, hence the question: _How to use sed w command inside {}?_